# Angular2: angular-cli production works in Chrome, not IE or FF

Tags: angular

Angular2: angular-cli production works in Chrome, not IE or FF
all is well here: http://secure.digitalsignage.com/boiler/
when using chrome but try in IE or FF and bunch of errors.

and I have pollyfills:
main.ts

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

any ideas?

this is the project:
https://github.com/born2net/Angular-kitchen-sink

regards

Sean

Comment: http://secure.digitalsignage.com/boiler/ does not work in chrome (e is not a function etc)

Comment: Definitely a missing polyfill. Corejs is not the only one needed.

Comment: I know I was thinking same thing, but I have it.. will update question so you can see...

Comment: ya I saw that as well e is not a function but no idea why... works great in Chrome.. :/

Comment: can anyone post which polyfillsthey are using as I still can't get it working in IE or FF... it must be polyfills as Chrome works great... regards

Answer (score 0):

found the issue, I missed a `this` and Chrome was fine with it, IE and FF not.. fixed!

tx

Sean

Comment: Hi.  Can you explain what you mean you "missed a this"?